# How do I rotate the screen by X degrees?

Tags: nvidia, xserver, display-rotation, viewports

I am creating an interactive project which runs on lubuntu (with nvidia drivers) and where the screen is tilted by 42 degrees. I would like to counteract this rotation in the viewport by rotating it the same amount in the other direction.

Is this possible to do?